# Adobe Flash Substitute

Tags: ipad

I am on a flight that requires Adobe flashplayer if I want to watch movies. I have an Ipad 2 and wonder if there is another Apple app that will work?

Comment: I'm missing something. Why does the flight require flash??

Comment: Out of interest, which Airline is it offering on board entertainment using WiFi?

Comment: @Buscar웃 They all do

Comment: @ghoppe The flight doesn't require flash, watching movies does.  Take, for example, YouTube - plays videos using Adobe Flash

Comment: @cullub YouTube has offered an [HTML5 player](https://www.youtube.com/html5) that doesn't require flash for five years now.

Comment: Wow I'm behind the times!  I didn't know that - must've gotten stuck back in 2010 or so.

Answer (score 1):

[Puffin Browser](http://www.puffinbrowser.com/index.php) (free with limitations, 99¢ to subscribe for 6 months)

[Photon Flash Player](http://www.appsverse.com/Browser) ($9.99)

You could also use many remote desktop applications to stream from a desktop PC or Mac. Probably doesn't help much on a flight, though.

Source: http://www.computerworld.com/article/2599798/apple-ios/how-to-run-flash-on-your-ipad-if-you-must.html